# ...as they were?

Tags: meaning

> The investigation of nature advanced hand in hand with the
> geographical discoveries, the development of trade and transport, the
> improvement of machinery and manufactures. The greatest strides were
> made in the mechanical sciences, closely connected as they were with
> the needs of technology.

[Materialism and the Dialectical Method - Maurice Cornforth]

What does "**as they were**" mean?

Answer (score 1):

The phrase 'as *something is/was/are/were*' can be used after a noun or noun phrase, and before mentioning something else which is notably and relevantly true of whatever *something* is.

The greatest strides were made in the mechanical sciences, **which were, we note,** closely connected with the needs of technology.

It is shameful that our town's chief of police has been found guilty of corruption, employed **as he was** to uphold the law.

Comment: Could I paraphrase it like this: "The greatest strides were made in the mechanical sciences, they were closely connected with the needs of technology"?

Comment: I'd prefer 'which were closely connected...'

Comment: @XVI You can't paraphrase it exactly that way, because what you have done is an error called a *comma splice*.  You have two complete sentences there - *the greatest strides were made in the mechanical sciences* and *they were closely connected with the needs of technology* - and you're sticking them together with just a comma between them.